# Customize tick transform attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Horizontal axis, datetimes

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(d3.time.hours, 3)
    .tickSize(-200)
```

Range on scale(x) is [0, 100]

Output SVG XML

```
<g class="xAxis" transform="translate(0, 182)">
    <g style="opacity: 1;" transform="translate(0,0)">
        <line class="tick" y2="-200" x2="0"></line>
        <text y="3" x="0" dy=".71em" style="text-anchor: middle;">Tue 15</text>
    </g>
    <g style="opacity: 1;" transform="translate(12.5,0)">
        <line class="tick" y2="-200" x2="0"></line>
        <text y="3" x="0" dy=".71em" style="text-anchor: middle;">03 AM</text>
    </g>
    <g style="opacity: 1;" transform="translate(25,0)">
        <line class="tick" y2="-200" x2="0"></line>
        <text y="3" x="0" dy=".71em" style="text-anchor: middle;">06 AM</text>
    </g>
    ...
```

Just don't know how to get inside that transform attribute and use percentages for the translations instead => (0%, 12.5%, 25%, so on...)

Complete code

```
var width = 960;
var height = 200;
var container = d3.select(".timeTable")
var svg = container.append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", height)
var roomID = container.attr("data-room")

function draw(times) {
    // domain
    var floor = d3.time.day.floor(d3.min(times, function (d) { return new Date(d.from); }));
    var ceil = d3.time.day.ceil(d3.max(times, function (d) { return new Date(d.until); }));
    // define linear time scale
    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([floor, ceil])
        .range([0, 100])
    // define x axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient('bottom')
        .ticks(d3.time.hours, 3)
        .tickSize(-200)
    // draw time bars
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(times)
        .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "timeRange")
            .attr("width", function (d, i) { return x(new Date(d.until)) - x(new Date(d.from)) + "%" })
            .attr("height", "10px")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) { return x(new Date(d.from)) + "%" })
            .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * 11 })
    // draw x axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "xAxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height - 18) + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
}

d3.json("/time/get/" + roomID, draw);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You should be able to place the ticks at arbitrary positions by setting input/output domains.

Comment: Yup - if I set the range to the ends of the container the ticks show up fine. What I'd like to do is place them relative to the container width so should it change, the positions of the ticks will adjust. I realize this might be a CSS frame of mind - I am open to other ideas for flexible graphs. Are the attributes of these tick `<g>` elements untouchable?

Comment: If you calculate the positions yourself, you could simply select the elements after they have been generated and modify the `transform` attribute accordingly. AFAIK d3 doesn't support any customisation of that attribute by itself.